# The python says that " the 'pyspark ' has no attiribute 'ml' " and I dont know how to solve this problem

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am stuck on a problem. So I will really appreciate if you help me a little.

First, I installed 'pyspark' through cmd, using 'pip install pyspark' command.

second, I imported pyspark, and tried to use pyspark.ml packages. but It says that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikniw.png)

In short, they said that "module 'pyspark' has no attribute ml"

But the pyspark.sql code works well, and I apparently have the ml files too..

I dont know what is the problem.

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLma.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. The problem is that packages don't work like modules; importing `pyspark` does not mean you can write `pyspark.ml` just because there is a `ml` folder. `from pyspark.ml import Pipeline` should work, you just made two typos in that line.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @AnaClaudia Hi.. the version is 3.8 Thanks a lot for helping me..

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thankyou I didnt know that I should not post images of code..